# Can my Ubuntu still load or run without the /boot partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, 22.04

I have a dual boot computer. A couple of weeks earlier, my Ubuntu was not loading so I reformatted my Ubuntu partition. After fixing everything, my Ubuntu now works perfectly fine but now my Windows 11 proceeded to BSOD. The partition in my SSD drive are as follows:

| Device | FS | Mountpoints |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /dev/nvme0n1p1 | ext4 | /, /var/snap |
| /dev/nvme0n1p3 | fat32 | /boot /efi |
| /dev/nvme0n1p4 | ext4 | /home |
| /dev/nvme0n1p7 | linux-swap | --- |
| /dev/nvme0n1p5 | ntfs | /media |
| /dev/nvme0n1p6 | ntfs | ---- |

Based on what I searched, there was a problem with the EFI partition that prevented the loading of Windows 11. I think this occurred after the most recent Ubuntu update. So what I am hoping to do is back up my Ubuntu settings without /boot then reformat the /boot partition so I can re-install Windows. But will that affect the booting of Ubuntu or should I do an overhaul of the entire SSD? If I will do that, can I restore my previously backed up Ubuntu settings on a freshly reformatted drive? Hopefully someone can help me with my issue. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't provide Ubuntu 22.04 LTS product details; but a default Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop install for example does **not** use a boot partition; only ESP (*EFI System Partition*) as is required to boot on uEFI/Secure-uEFI hardware.. that is loaded onto `/boot/efi` but it's not a boot partition. Windows isn't impacted by anything on Ubuntu's boot (though it may share or have its own ESP which isn't /boot).  Your `nvme0n1p3` looks like an ESP (*with error in spacing though!*) but isn't a `/boot`  (loading to `/boot/efi` only at most)